# Вычисление ширины input

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Как сделать вот так, как показано на картинке,только вместо **div** **B**, будет располагаться **input**?

Контейнер в качестве **div**, содержит в себе два **div**.

**div A**, имеет фиксированную ширину.

ширина **div** **B**, должна рассчитываться в процентах от оставшегося свободного места.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это

```html
<div style="width: 50%; background-color: green;  margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 30px;"> 
        <div style="float: left; height: 32px; width: 32px; border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; background-color: red; "></div>    
        <div style="height: 32px; width: 98%; border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; background-color: #EEEEEE;"></div>
</div>
```

НО  если использовать вместо  DIV **B**, input
то он не рассчитывается так как div

```html
<div style="width: 50%; background-color: green;  margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 30px;"> 
        <div style="float: left; height: 32px; width: 32px; border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; background-color: red; "></div>    
        <input style="display: block; height: 32px; width: 98%; border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; background-color: #EEEEEE;" type="text" size="20" placeholder="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать функцию `calc()`. Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/q0rksjsx/1/

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk Я обновил свой вопрос, обратите внимание.

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk Интересненько хм..

Comment: Для инпута можно тоже самое применить!

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk Дело в том, что без инпута, всё работает хорошо. А вот если вставить его, то он начнут вычисляться по другому, от общей ширины.  Если использовать  calc, то рассчет так-же будет не точным, и input, будет смещаться вниз из-за нехватки места.

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk calc - не варинат

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk По крайней мере с input он плохо работает

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, и с чего это ты вдруг принимаешь какой-то бредовый неработающий ответ???

Comment: [Пора на мету.](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4359/178988)

Comment: @Qwertiy Что за бред ты пишешь? Ответ отличный и он работает хорошо. Другие люди тоже подтвердили это. Разве ты это не видишь?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, я [в последнем комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498362/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-input?noredirect=1#comment835908_609726) тоже подтвердил. Только вот на момент принятия он таким ну ни как не был.

Comment: @Qwertiy Может его изменили. Я точно помню что  в процессе решения этого вопроса, я опробовал разные механизмы, тестировал, и этот ответ который я подтвердил, подошел лучше всего. Может со временем его как то изменили, я не знаю. Да там и другие люди его одобрили, большинство. Я честно, не хочу в этмо кататься, у меня просто к сожалению нету времени на это, зачем? Я всё сделал как нужно, ничего не нарушил, да и никто тут ничего не нарушил. Возможно что как-то ответ изменили, но я не знаю тогда что с этим делать. Пускай Администрация разбирается с этим.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, 2 дня назад после публикации нового ответа ты (даже модераторы не могут менять принятый ответ на чужой вопрос) изменил принятый ответ на новый (который дал Vadizar). На тот момент его ответ явно принципиально не был работоспособным, но за эти 2 дня он смог привести ответ к нормальному виду. Собственно, на этом всё.

Comment: @Qwertiy  О, так это я по моёму как раз твой ответ и выбирал, именно это решение было лучшим. Так как такое произошло, может как то по случайности я нажал, я не знаю. Я помню что в том решении применялся `table-cell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0;
}

.wrapper > div:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div><input></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так действительно отлично, во всяком случае минусов пока не нашел ) Спасибо!

Comment: А Вы сами пишите, или в прогре какой-то? И если без проги то почему?)

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, не понял вопрос.

Comment: При написании css стилей, задействуете ли Вы какую-ту программу, типа Adobe Dreamweaver CC, или подобную? Если Вы не используете такие программы, то почему? А если используете, то какую именно? И еще последний вопросик, если можно: Если у вас что то наподобие собственного bootstrap?

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, конечно НЕ использую. Даже не знаю, с чем сравнить... Чем по-твоему подобная программа должна помочь?

Comment: Это интересно, спасибо, все верно.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, что имеется в виду под собственным bootstrap'ом? Если какие-то шаблоны и заготовки кода, то нет. Для примеров я просто пишу минимальный пример - нет причин городить там всякие типовые шаблоны. Да и вообще, я не сторонник городить огород там, где можно обойтись без него. Если нечто типа своего фреймвёрка с базовыми стилями, то снова нет :)

Comment: @Vadizar, а если хочешь, чтобы доходил, поменяй `width: 90%` на `width: 100%` и будет прям идеально доходить. И именно доходить, а не вылазить.

Comment: Это однозначно не лучший ответ.

Comment: @Vadizar, а как-то аргументировать можешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy меньше переменных, выше кроссбраузерность. И мой способ был лучшим. Не знаю, что ты там напутил, наверное сам поставил.

Comment: @Vadizar, принять ответ может только автор вопроса. Даже модераторы не могут. Что ты имеешь в виду под переменными? DOM-элементы? Да, у меня на один элемент больше. Что касается кроссбраузерности, у моего варианта поддержка IE8+, а если использовать реальную таблицу вместо display, то будет IE 5.5+, т. е. станет работать даже в IE Quirks 5. А наиболее актуальный вариант (на мой взгляд) - вообще новый ответ с флексбоксом, но он для IE10+. А вот как твой способ работает, я что-то не очень понимаю...

Comment: @Qwertiy в том-то и дело, что вы не профессиональный Markup Developer, вот и не знаете основ. Под переменными я имею ввиду количество фиксированных значений.

К тому же, ваш способ не будет работать в IE 8. Псевдокласс :last-child появился лишь в спецификациях CSS 3.

Comment: @Vadizar, по поводу количества значений я не совсем согласен. Следует количество всяких магических значений уменьшать - это да. Но у меня так заданы только размеры левого блока (и их можно убрать), а остальное сводится к значениям `0` и `100%` - они обычно безвредны.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию `calc` Например:

```css
.a {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 0; /*для отображения текста в блоках не забудьте задать размер шрифта им.*/
}
.b, .c {
  display: inline-block; /* можно использовать свойство float */
  vertical-align: top; 
}
.b {
  width: 200px;
  outline: 3px solid green;
  height: 400px;
}

.c {
  width: calc(80% - 200px); /* расчет ширины */
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

[http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc](http://%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%20calc();)

Вариант и инпутом:

```css
.a {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 0; /*для отображения текста в блоках не забудьте задать размер шрифта им.*/
  line-height: 50px;
  
}
.b, c{
  display: inline-block; /* можно использовать свойство float */
  vertical-align: top;
 
  
}
.b {
  width: 50px;
  outline: 3px solid green;
  height: 50px;
}

.c {
  width: calc(80% - 200px); /* расчет ширины */
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <input class="c" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Почитайте комментарии который я писал выше, пожалуйста.

Comment: И вопрос был про - Вычисление ширины input

Comment: тот вопрос что я читал был про див, сейчас и инпут сделаем....

Comment: обновил с инпутом.

Answer (score 2):

Описание вопроса и изображение несет разный смысл. Пример ниже ориентируется на описание и в нем заключен базовый принцип работы универсального решения, которое вы сами сможете легко дополнить необходимыми свойствами:

```css
.divMain:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.divA {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
.divB {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.divB input {
  width: 100%;

  /* Reset CSS */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  /* End Reset CSS */
}
```

```html
<div class="divMain">
  <div class="divA">
    Какой-то важный контент.
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
    <input type="text" placeholder="">
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Отмечу, что .divA не должен быть пустым, а если предполагается, что он может не иметь контента - дополните его свойством min-height: 1;

P.S.S. В некоторых браузерах input может выходить за рамки контейнера из-за дефолтных стилей (margin и неверного значения border-box) - это легко исправляется обнулением стилей, к примеру [godlike.css](https://github.com/1000tech/godlike.css). Если в глобальных стилях проекта вы уже переопределили дефолтные стили, советую убрать блок Reset CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Также можно использовать flexbox. Задаём одному элементу фиксированную ширину, а второму — `flex-grow: 1`, заставляя его занимать оставшееся пространство. Этот способ в отличие от `float`

- гарантирует нахождение элементов на одной строке
- позволяет контенту иметь динамическую высоту (`height: auto;`) и соседние элементы контейнера будет подстраиваться под неё как таблица
- требует намного меньше кода и не нуждается в хаках вроде `float`, `clearfix` и `overflow`.

Пример кода:

```css
* {
  /* Чтобы задать ширину и высоту, вкючая padding и border */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.fixed {
  width: 30px;
}

.fluid {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.fluid > input[type="text"] {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed">
    30px
  </div>
  <div class="fluid">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пардон, я там перепутал вас и ответил как будто автору ответа. )

Answer (score 0):

Навскидку вот так. Основная идея - использовать функцию `calc` : `width: calc(100% - 30px - 10%);`

```css
.main {
  background: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
.one {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.two {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 30px - 10%);
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <input type="text" class="two" />
</div>
```

Comment: Неплохо, но не идеально. А так не плохо.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, потому что правильная формула `(100% - 30px) * 0.9`. И пробел в разметке надо убрать.