# 2 div в ряд: один резиновый, другой фиксированный

Tags: css, html

Необходимо на страничке сделать 2 блока, которые бы в сумме занимали всю возможную ширину. Правый блок узкий и не должен изменять своего размера при растяжении или сжатии страницы, а левый должен занимать всю оставшуюся ширину. Попробовал своими силами, но либо левый блок занимает не всё пространство, либо выдавливает правый на новую строку, а такого быть не должно.

```css
.div3 {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.div1 {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 550px;
  background: #f99;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}

.div2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: #99f;
  display: inline-block; 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="div3">
  <div class="div1">Резиновый блок</div>
  <div class="div2">Фиксированный</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисление ширины input](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498362/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-input)

Comment: @Grundy Да я бы не сказал, что это дубликат, так как там вопрос по картинке и про input, там ещё куча доп. требований. Там ещё 50% окна надо чтобы занималось и т.д., короче какой-то он очень специфический. Уверен, что текущий вопрос задавался, но я бы поиск бы другой вариант.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, возможно стоит наоборот закрыть. По сути вопросы одинаковы: один блок фиксированной ширины, второй нет

Comment: @Grundy Ну не так они и похожи. Если искать чисто концептуальную схожесть, то можно большую часть вопросов по HTML\CSS позакрывать, так как принципы решения часто одни и те же.

Answer (score 3):

Я знаю, что [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) так может. Его, правда, стоит применять с осторожностью, в IE он [багованный](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
.fixed {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: #FF9999;
}
.rubbery {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  background-color: #9999FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rubbery"></div>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Очень плохо работает с мобильника :( Других вариантов нет?

Comment: @molegos, используйте таблицу

Comment: Таблица для разметки это прошлый век =)

Comment: @Vadizar, прекрати этот вандализм! Ты решил во всех темах отметиться?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите внимательно, у вас `.div2` сейчас никак не фиксирован. Задайте ему `width` явно.

Для вашей задачи `display: inline-block` не нужно, уберите его.
Уберите из `.div1` параметр `max-width`.

Поставьте для `.div1` свойство `float: right,` если блоки пшменяютмя местами, исправил их положение в html-коде.

Должно помочь.

Comment: Спорный вопрос я больше предпочитаю использовать именно `inline-block` IE7 его поддерживает,а делать для более древнего смысла нет....
Вопрос лишь в умении пользоваться и правильном понимании этих правил....

Comment: По моему мнению inline-block и block немного для разных задач. Например в вашем примере применение inline-block и float одновременно нецелесообразно, так как с точки зрения разметки выполняют одну и ту же задачу.

Comment: Сделал ваш вариант - резиновый растягивается на всю ширину и выталкивает фиксированный на новую строку :(

Answer (score 1):

Подобный вопрос уже [обсуждался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498362/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-input/498371#498371).

В вашем коде нужно применять либо `float`, либо `inline-block`.
и вычислять размер резинового блока с помощью функции `calc`.
Если использовать `float`, то не забывайте про `clear`, при использовании `inline-block` необходимо у элемента родителя убить размер шрифта, для того чтобы убить пробелы между блоками,которые возникнут так как блоки приобретут все свойства строчных элементов. `vertical-align: top` в данном случае задается для того,что-бы блоки не съезжали вниз при добавлении текста  в них.
Пробуйте эксперементируйте....... Однако разметка на`float` уже устарела и все чаще используют именно `inline-block`. Более продвинутые технологии позволяют использовать Flex, но его поддерживают только современные браузеры... и если ваш проект не нацелен на кроссбраузерность, то лучше конечно использовать его.

Вот пример:

```css
.a {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 0; /*для отображения текста в блоках не забудьте задать размер шрифта им.*/
}
.b, .c {
  display: inline-block; /* можно использовать свойство float */
  vertical-align: top; 
}
.b {
  width: 200px;
  outline: 3px solid green;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.c {
  width: calc(100% - 200px); /* расчет ширины */
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">фиксированный</div>
  <div class="c">резиновый</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Знать современные возможности `flexbox` и `calc` хорошо, но вот знать основы - куда важнее:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.divMain:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.divA {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  background: #99f;
}
.divB {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f99;
}
```

```html
<div class="divMain">
  <div class="divA">
    Фиксированный блок
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
    Резиновый блок
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Порядок блоков в разметке важен.

Comment: Можете унижительную часть "Смотрю я на ответы с flexbox и calc и слезы наворачиваются." убрать или переформулировать?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov готов.

Comment: Знать современные возможности CSS хорошо, но вот знать основы - куда важнее:" Это вы основами называете разработку с хаками вроде `float`, `clear`, `overflow`, которые раннее использовались ввиду отсутствия достойный альтернатив? Табличную вёрстку и абсолютное позиционирование в расчёт не берём.

Comment: Я не спорю, что у вас идеальный ответ для тех кому надо IE7-9 поддерживать, но просто только старый CSS считать основами, как мне кажется, неверно. Знать CSS3 разве не основы?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov это не хаки, а именно основы. Мой вариант поддерживается большим количеством браузеров, при этом он требует меньше переменных, что делает его наиболее приемлемым вариантом.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov делать блок ячейкой или вычислять ширину основного блока от ширины сайдбара - это как раз и есть хак. В том, чтобы очищать поток - нет ничего плохого. Тем более, это не обязательно условие работы моего примера.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov под основами я имею ввиду базовые возможности CSS и HTML, которые использовали еще наши "деды". Для этих вопросов решения давно придуманы и подходят по сей день. А варианты с таблицами и кальком больше напоминают велосипед.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51071/discussion-between-vadim-ovchinnikov-and-vadizar).

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант:

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
.fixed,
.rubbery{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 25px;
}
.fixed {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #FF9999;
}
.rubbery {  
  background-color: #9999FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rubbery">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
  <div class="fixed"> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если строить таблицу с помощью css свойств, она так же ресурсоемка как и HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Некропост уже, но сегодня задался тем же вопросом по коду и ничего толкового не нашёл.

Делал для себя **форму поиска**, которая во многих местах на сайте стоит и везде разные "родители".

---

**Плюсы:**

- ширина левого блока всегда 100%, без погрешностей, а ширина правого блока фиксированная и её можно менять на любую
- использование display:table(table-cell) и position, а не flex, т.е. это старая вёрстка
- резиновая высота контейнера

---

**Минусы:**

- не обнаружено

---

```css
/* Блок-родитель */

.search-box {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Блок-чайлд, который отравняет контент внутри себя по вертикали по центру */

.search {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Общий блок */

.search .search-blocks {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 62px;
  /* Отступ справа для блока с фиксированной шириной */
}


/* Левый блок */

.search .search-block-child-1 {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Правый блок */

.search .search-block-child-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* Ставим его справа общего блока */
}


/* Общие стили для поля ввода и кнопки поиска */

.search input[type="text"],
.search input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Обязательно (!!!), чтобы форма не ушла за ширину общего блока */
}


/* Поле ввода поиска */

.search input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: text;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #e6e6e6;
}


/* Кнопка поиска */

.search input[type="submit"] {
  width: 56px;
  /* Та самая фиксированная ширина кнопки (можно заменить её блоком) */
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #f2f2f2;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2f2f2, #ddd);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
  <form action="SITESEARCHENGINEHERE" method="get" class="search">
    <div class="search-blocks">
      <div class="search-block-child search-block-child-1">
        <input type="text" id="searchfocus" name="s" value="" placeholder="Поиск по сайту...">
      </div>
      <div class="search-block-child search-block-child-2">
        <input type="submit" value="Найти">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```