# Растянуть div на всю свободную (максимальную) ширину

Tags: html, css

Есть два блока. Первый блок имеет динамическую ширину, т.е. ширина зависит от содержимого. Второй блок должен быть растянут на всю остальную (свободную) ширину.

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Содержимое</div>
  <div class="child max">Второе содержимое</div>
</div>
```

Как можно с помощью CSS растянуть второй блок на всю свободную ширину?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисление ширины input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498362/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-input)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502709/2-div-в-ряд-один-резиновый-другой-фиксированный?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Знаю два хороших метода, как растянуть второй блок на всю свободную (максимальную) ширину:

1. Современный метод ― с помощью flexbox.

   ```css
   .parent {
     display: flex;
     border: 2px solid red;
     height: 30px;
     line-height: 26px;
   }
   .child {
     display: block;
     border: 2px solid blue;
   }
   /* Растягиваем второй блок на максимальнуцю ширину */
   .child.max {
     flex: 1;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">Содержимое</div>
     <div class="child max">Второе содержимое</div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Один из необычных методов ― использовать float и overflow. Overflow создаёт отдельный контекст форматирования для выбранного элемента, тем самым локализуя действие свойства float внутри элемента к которому применён. [Подробнее...](https://habrahabr.ru/post/48383/)

   ```css
   .parent {
     border: 2px solid red;
     line-height: 26px;
     overflow: auto; /* Это чтобы родитель не терял высоту */
   }
   .child {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     border: 2px solid blue;
   }
   /* Растягиваем второй блок на максимальнуцю ширину */
   .child.max {
     float: none;
     overflow: auto;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">Содержимое</div>
     <div class="child max">Второе содержимое</div>
   </div>
   ```

***Уточнение: overflow должен быть единственным в родителе и находится после всех float.***

Comment: если будет длинная строка - блок не растянется в высоту

Comment: @Grundy, какой блок?

Comment: Любой. Во втором примере вообще все печально становится

Comment: @Grundy, вопрос был про ширину. Полную высоту делать не обязательно...